# PHP newbie -- turning register_globals back on

Tags: php

I'm working with an existing website based on OSCommerce.  When I attempt to access my working copy locally, it displays a message saying PHP.ini has register globals off and they need to be on.  I have read that the default has changed, and understand the reasons behind it, but for now I want to get this working without having to install an older PHP version.

I figured I could turn register_globals back on by putting the following line in php.ini:

```
register_globals = On
```

But the site still tells me that register_globals is turned off.

I restarted Apache; that didn't help.  I tried putting

```
<? echo get_ini('register_globals'); ?>
```

onto the page; it doesn't show anything.  (I'm not sure that's the right statement for that.)

What do I need to do to turn on register_globals, and/or how do I echo settings like this so I can tell what they are?

Comment: You might need to restart your webserver.

Comment: Look in `<? phpinfo(); ?>` for the `php.ini` path. Many systems have multiple `php.ini` files; make sure you're updating the right one. Also, make sure your PHP is older than 5.4, as that's the version where the feature [was removed](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php).

Comment: **DO NOT USE `REGISTER_GLOBALS`**

Comment: @MrTux: as stated, I restarted the webserver.

Comment: @cept0: technically speaking, I didn't use register_globals.  But the site I'm working with did, surely you aren't suggesting that I rewrite the site so that it doesn't use them?

Comment: @Dan: I missed that in the documentation; in one version the default value was changed, but as of 5.4 it can't be set to On?  I'll check the phpinfo as well, but first will have to back off from 5.4.16.  Thanks.

Comment: @All Downvoters: I really don't see the problem here.  Just what is wrong with this question?  It isn't the sort of thing that is easy to find in the documentation unless you already know where to look.

Comment: @arcy What is the URL of the website? I'd love to know for some experiments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[php.net/...](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php)

> This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

Starting from PHP 5.4, `register_globals` has been deprecated.

Also, the right function to get ini settings is `ini_get`. So use `ini_get('register_globals')` to retreive the value.

Edit: I'm not sure what version of PHP you have.